# Set custom css variable using hostbinding

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to make a component customizable by having the color as an input.
In the end, I want to be able to use the component like this `<component-name color="myColor"></component-name>`:

To start with, I'm trying to set the css variable using hostbinding, like this:

```js
 @HostBinding('style.--color') myColor: string = '--blue'
```

```css
:host {
  --blue: #5dbbbb;
  --green: #286e22;

  background-color: var(--color);
}
```

But the blue never renders. If I inspect the component in chrome, I can see that it has
`"background-color: --color"` When I look at the variable it's defined as `--color: --blue`

It works fine if I use the hex code directly `(@HostBinding('style.--color') myColor: string = '#xxxxxx')` instead of the css variable for the color, but I want to avoid that if possible. Any thoughts on what could be wrong? I'm using Angular14.

Comment: Shouldnt it be `@HostBinding('style.--color') myColor: string = 'var(--blue)'`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your HostBinding code

this

```html
 @HostBinding('style.--color') myColor: string = '--blue'
```

to

```html
 @HostBinding('style.--color') myColor: string = 'var(--blue)'
```

And it should work